# selecting an integers to maximise sum

Tags: algorithm, math

if we are given pairs of integers `(a1,b1),(a2,b2),(a3,b3),..(an,bn)` and there is a maximum sum value = `X` then how can we select the given pairs such that sum of the first entries (i.e. a1, a2,..ap)amongst the selected pairs is `maximum but <= X` ? E.g if the given pairs are `(43,9),(57,12),(13,4)` and maximum sum is `71` then the pairs we can select are `(57,12)` and `(13,4)` giving a maximum sum <=71(X) as 70 . 
My initial approach is to sort the pairs based on first entry values in descending order and then maybe an O(n^2) algorithm ..but am not sure about this and it also may be too slow for large amount of data..So is there any efficient approach to it?
Thanks.

Comment: I am confused, how can the maximum sum simultaneously be X and <=X(unless its just X, in which case why have the <?).  Furthermore, how do the pairs of #s fit in?  I think you might be missing or misunderstanding part of the question.(EDIT) OK, I think I get it, you are GIVEN a maximum sum(X) and have to pick the pairs that are <=X)

Comment: i mean the sum of first entries must be maximum but at the same time < X .E.g we cannot take 57,12 and 43,9 as 57+43 > 71

Comment: I think `pranay`it is Dynamic Programming Problem. go through some search for maximum sum problem in dynamic programming which might help you. but still usuaully in this specific case that will also give O(n^2) but I think we can do this in O(n) by something like this : 

First just consider the first part of the pair okay like 43, 57 and 13 then like weighted interval scheduling problem of DP i.e. u cn get the soln of the prob by somthng like : `either ith value would be in the solution or it wont be there comes the recursive design so solution is either ith member or it is from i-1th member`

Comment: If you want to improve the algo. go through some problem DP first and then try to think in terms of recursive definition of the algo..you will understand what I mean by recursive formula when you read the material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like this could be implemented with a modification of the [0-1 Knapsack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) problem.

Comment: Thanks..still overall complexity would be O(n^2) i guess.

Comment: I believe it would be O(nX), which could be O(n^2) if n == X

Comment: The complexity would depend also on the values of the n integers, as (100,2)(201,2)(350,7) with X = 95, would perform very little work using the memo-ized recursive version.